# Fixing Audio Problem

Tags: raspbian, audio, kali, riscos

I have using raspi and wondering to fix some complicated issue for me because of my less of experience. One of the problems is how to configure the audio for Raspberry Pi in several Oses (I am using Raspbian, Kali, Risc Os, and Flint OS). By the way, I am using RPi 3 and only in analog audio output, because my display still in VGA port mode. This is the detail:

Raspbian : I was using this one for the first time, and there is no problem since i've used `amixer cset numid=3 1` (for analog output) command. But now, i am not using this one, because I am using the card for another OS.

Kali Linux: I have type `apt-get install alsa-utils` ;  `sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835`; `sudo amixer cset numid=3` ; and the summary of the commands was becoming `Mixer: no such file or directory`

Risc Os: Ooh, This kind of OS is so Scary and too strange for me. So, we have no priority with this one . But still receiving on your suggestion.

Flint Os: This os is rich enough, and I found the audio controller from the right-bottom menu. But, it was useless and I still can't solve my problem. The option of menu are `bcm2835 ALSA:bcm2835 ALSA 0.0 (USB)` and `bcm2835 ALSA:bcm2835 IEC1958/HDMI`, but no result or some change with the options. There is no terminal at this one or I can't found it till now.

And thanks for the helps :)

Comment: You could read my old tutorial I wrote for SailPi
https://sailpi.wordpress.com/tweaks/hdmi-sound-through-pulseaudio/

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to use a standard name to change the control value. For example one name which is present on most systems is "Master" which is the master output of the soundcard.

You can see the available simple controls like so :

```
amixer scontrols
```

You can get and set the volume using the sset command like so (for Master) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ amixer sset Master 50%
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [50%] [-57.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [50%] [-57.00dB]
```